# Image cut after being uploaded to webapi

Tags: image, azure, asp.net-web-api2

I use this code to upload images in asp.net webapi:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("imageBrowser/insert")]
[SharePointContextWebAPIFilter]
public object PostFile()
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
    if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }


    string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);


    //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The file is not being uploaded correctly, it looks like this
[image]

Is this related to azure? Is there something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you're using async code in a non async method. So the thread is being finished before ending the read part.

try this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("imageBrowser/insert")]
[SharePointContextWebAPIFilter]
public async object PostFile()
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
    if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }


    string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);


    //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```